# React Native - build apk with plugins

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native

I’m using `react-native-push-notifications` to send local notifications on my react native app. The app works perfectly on my android emulator and on any physical device while using `react-native run-android`. But when I signed my app and build an apk throw gradlew assemblerelease the apk builds without compiling `react-native-push-notifications` and the app does not send notifications. I think I should link the plugin with `build.gradle` but I’ve searched for a while and didn’t figure how.